# How to use same jQuery function trigger different mouse over action?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to use single jQuery function to trigger different mouse over function to display different content. Here are my HTML and Jquery code. Could you help me simplify it? Or find other better solution?

**HTML**

```
  <div class="container home-firstscreen-main">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-2">
        <ul class="list-unstyled category-nav">
         <li role="presentation"><a href="#" class="home-link">Home</a></li>
         <li role="presentation"><a href="#" class="profile-link">Profile</a></li>
         <li role="presentation"><a href="#" class="messages-link">Messages</a></li>
       </ul>
     </div>
     <div class="col-lg-6">
       <div class="mega-menu-show">
         <ul class="list-unstyled home-items">
           <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Tony</a></li>
           <li role="presentation"><a href="#">stark</a></li>
         </ul>

         <ul class="list-unstyled profile-items">
           <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Captain</a></li>
           <li role="presentation"><a href="#">America</a></li>
         </ul>

         <ul class="list-unstyled messages-items">
           <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Black</a></li>
           <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Widow</a></li>
         </ul>
       </div>
      </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".category-nav a").on("mouseover", function () {
    $('.mega-menu-show').fadeIn();
    var catLinkClass = $(this).attr('class');
    var catLinkUse   = catLinkClass.replace('-link', '');
    $('.mega-menu-show .' + catLinkUse +'-items').show();
});
// show category nav on mouse out
$(".category-nav a").on("mouseout", function () {
    $('.mega-menu-show').fadeOut();
    $('.mega-menu-show ul').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an awesome solution, also needed to change the structure of the HTML. Thanks, everyone gave me the inspiration I needed.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container home-firstscreen-main">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-2">
            <ul class="list-unstyled category-nav">
             <li role="presentation"><a href="#" class="home-link">Home</a>
              <div class="mega-menu-show home-items">
               <ul class="list-unstyled">
                 <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Tony</a></li>
                 <li role="presentation"><a href="#">yaddaYaddaYadda</a></li>
                 <li role="presentation"><a href="#">pfftPfftPfft</a></li>
                </ul>
             </div>
           </li>
           <li role="presentation"><a href="#" class="profile-link">Profile</a>
            <div class="mega-menu-show profile-items">
             <ul class="list-unstyled">
               <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Wang</a></li>
               <li role="presentation"><a href="#">yaddaYaddaYadda</a></li>
               <li role="presentation"><a href="#">pfftPfftPfft</a></li>
             </ul>
           </div>
         </li>
         <li role="presentation"><a href="#" class="messages-link">Messages</a>
          <div class="mega-menu-show messages-items">
           <ul class="list-unstyled">
             <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Stark</a></li>
             <li role="presentation"><a href="#">yaddaYaddaYadda</a></li>
             <li role="presentation"><a href="#">pfftPfftPfft</a></li>
           </ul>
         </div>
       </li>
     </ul>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
     $('.category-nav>li').hover(function() {
  $(this).find(".mega-menu-show").fadeIn(200);
 }, function() {
  $(this).find(".mega-menu-show").fadeOut(100);
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got your point you can use something like this

```js
$(".category-nav a").on("mouseover", function () {
    $('.mega-menu-show').fadeIn();
    var catLinkClass = $(this).attr('class');
    var catLinkUse   = catLinkClass.replace('-link', '');
    $('.mega-menu-show [class$="-items"]').hide();
    $('.mega-menu-show .' + catLinkUse +'-items').show();
});
// show category nav on mouse out
$(".mega-menu-show").on("mouseleave", function () {
    $(this).fadeOut();
});
```

```css
.mega-menu-show [class$="-items"]{
  display : none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container home-firstscreen-main">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-2">
        <ul class="list-unstyled category-nav">
         <li role="presentation"><a href="#" class="home-link">Home</a></li>
         <li role="presentation"><a href="#" class="profile-link">Profile</a></li>
         <li role="presentation"><a href="#" class="messages-link">Messages</a></li>
       </ul>
     </div>
     <div class="col-lg-6">
       <div class="mega-menu-show">
         <ul class="list-unstyled home-items">
           <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Tony</a></li>
           <li role="presentation"><a href="#">stark</a></li>
         </ul>

         <ul class="list-unstyled profile-items">
           <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Captain</a></li>
           <li role="presentation"><a href="#">America</a></li>
         </ul>

         <ul class="list-unstyled messages-items">
           <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Black</a></li>
           <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Widow</a></li>
         </ul>
       </div>
      </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in an single jQuery function like this.

```
$(document).on({
    mouseover: function () {
        $('.mega-menu-show').fadeIn();
        var catLinkClass = $(this).attr('class');
        var catLinkUse = catLinkClass.replace('-link', '');
        $('.mega-menu-show .' + catLinkUse + '-items').show();
    },
    // show category nav on mouse out
    mouseout: function () {
        $('.mega-menu-show').fadeOut();
        $('.mega-menu-show ul').hide();
    }
}, ".category-nav a");
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/z7rLdjn2/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: and when he want to click on the dropdown list what should he do?? in your code it will disappear   right??

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef I just simplified the OP's mouse actions into single function. But I didn't change any behavior of the code.

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, you can simplify your code by combining the 2 vars into 1.

```
$(".category-nav a").on("mouseover", function () {
    $('.mega-menu-show').fadeIn();
    var catLinkClass = $(this).attr('class').replace('link', 'items');
    $('.mega-menu-show .' + catLinkClass).show();
});
// show category nav on mouse out
$(".category-nav a").on("mouseout", function () {
    $('.mega-menu-show').fadeOut();
});
```